# How to create a div to fit in webview in android

Tags: android, html, webview, scale

I am looking for an approach to fit a div element into a webview. The challenge is to scale the div to fit a webview on different Android devices.

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
String divElement = "<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;> STUFF </div>";
wv.loadData(divElement, "text/html", "urf-8");
```

**Question:** How can I tell the WebView to "scale" to the 100px square which is created by the div? Or, are there better approaches to create the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use `width:100%` (or any other proportion) for the div? does it need to have an absolute value?